# Force Preview to open all selected images in one window

Tags: macos, finder, preview

Before mavericks, selecting several images in Finder and choosing Open on them would open them in Preview in *one* window, with all image thumbnails nicely on the left hand side bar.
Since Mavericks, this is no longer the case. Sometimes the selected images all appear in one window, sometimes Preview arbitrarily open some images in one window and other images in another window...
How can I force Preview to open all in one again?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: you can’t. This is a bug in Mavericks.

What I do is:

- Open the group of images
- Close all windows in Preview if it has opened more than one window (shortcut: <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>w</kbd>)
- Re-open the same group of images

Most of the time, I have all my images in one window the second time I open them.

Comment: In High Sierra you simply can't open multiple files in one window. No matter the preferences or how often you close and reopen them

Comment: @JulianF.Weinert One more High Sierra bug… The list is practically endless!

Answer (score 22):

Had the same problem. It's simply in the prefernces setup "open images in one window"

Comment: This is true, that's an answer! Someone give this guy the green check!

Comment: Ironic answer? Maybe I should check it just for the sake of it.

Comment: to be more precise:  preferences > general >  open all files in one window.

Comment: @jQwierdy No it's not. You probably had another problem than the original question. However it's great if your problem is solved!

Comment: This does not fix the issue / bug described by Jonny

Comment: Does not work when you have already other documents opened in Preview : the files you are opening will be added to to one of the already open documents. Imagine opening some .jpg images and they are added to a pdf that is open.

Answer (score 4):

Before reading [zinne's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/138484/38213), I avoided the problem by using *Quick Look* instead of *Preview*. It can be found in the context menu of selected images, between *Make alias* and *Share*, at least in my Maverics 10.9.5.

[image]

Comment: Great alternate solution which provided me with exactly what I needed for my specialized needs.

Answer (score 2):

I keep the Preview.app icon in my dock (OS X 10.9.5). Drag and drop a folder of images onto the Preview.app icon. This will open all images in a single Preview window.

Comment: Great idea, it works well!

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in High Sierra

Comment: Worked fine for me on High Sierra, this solution worked best for me, thanks!